# Wildcard in Word to find multiple words

Tags: ms-word, wildcard

In a word document i need to find all the words that start with a "<" and end with "keyword>". For example, ,  and so on...
I've found a standard regex for that, but since wildcards are not the same as regex, does anyone know an equivalent?
Thanx

Comment: For best results include a sample of your data and your desired output.

Comment: Removed the `regex` tag as `word` as far as I know does not support those.

Comment: This question is about Microsoft Word. As the description of the [\[word\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) tag says, “questions on the general usage of Microsoft Word are off-topic for Stack Overflow and should be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) instead.”

Comment: @RoryO'Kane No, the information for the WORD tag does *not* say that - it says something completely different. The Word tag is for questions concerning the term "word". MS-Word is the correct tag for Microsoft Word.